# Stop and copy garbage collector in OCAML

Tags: garbage-collection, iteration, ocaml

I have a homework assignment to finish writing a stopy-and-copy garbage collector in OCaml. There are 3 functions that need to be written. The first thing to be known is that a 64 slot array named ram will be what the garbage collector uses as memory. Each slot will contain an object of type 'cell'. That type may look like the following:

- Object (id, size, references)
- ObjData _
- Free
- FwdPointer (_)

I believe I am okay with the first function but the second function I need help with.
The function is:

`let rec scan_tospace (free : int) (unscanned : int) =`

Here is the objective of the function:

> (* Scan To-space, copy all referenced objects to the To-space and
>     update references in objects. Recurse until the free pointer is
>     identical to the unscanned pointer.
>
> [free] is the pointer to the next free address in the To-space,
>     [unscanned] is the address of the first unscanned object in the
>     To-space.
>
> Return the address of the free pointer after all objects have been
>     scanned.
>   *)

What I want to do is pattern matching on the element at the unscanned pointer. If it is an object (x,y,z) then I want the result to go through each element in the integer list z and apply the function 'let copy_obj (free : int) (addr : int) =' to it as the argument addr. The problem is that the function copy_obj takes 2 arguments and I can't figure out how to also insert the second argument when calling List.iter like so:

```
List.iter obj_copy free z
```

I've also tried this as the result when it successfully  matches with an object:

```
List.iter (fun k -> match k with
                | int k -> copy_obj free k) z;
```

There I get this:

```
Error: This expression has type int * int
       but an expression was expected of type unit
```

I didn't post any code on purpose, but if you'd liked see it I can post more. I didn't want to give any answers away. Also, I'm not look for someone to write any code for me, another reason I didn't post much of it. Any ideas in the right direction would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Post your code and show us your specific problem.

Comment: it can't say this because `List.iter (fun k -> match k with | int k -> copy_obj free k) z;` expression is syntactically incorrect

Comment: `obj_copy` or `copy_obj`? If you want meaningful answers from the community, you have to explain your problem correctly.

Comment: Your problem description itself is a problem. Solve that first please and I believe you can do it. If you can't, just post your original assignment (that your profession gave to u) directly.

Answer (score 0):

`List.iter obj_copy free z` should be `List.iter (obj_copy free) z` so the free is the first argument to obj_copy and the items in the list are the second. With this change you should get the same error as your later code.

The problem here is the use of List.iter. As you go over the referenced objects and copy them `free` has to change. Otherwise you copy each object over the previous one. You also need to remember where the copied objects now are so you can update the references in the outer object. Accordingly copy_obj returns (I assume) a tuple of the object and the new free.

You have to use `List.fold_left` or `List.fold_right` or manual recursion to go through the list while keeping track of free and the copied objects.